# Issue with R tidytext Package function unnest_tokens

Tags: r, unnest, tidytext

I want to do a bigram analysis using the function unnest_tokens from tidytext package. It worked a few weeks before but now my output is only NA.

I have following df `str(df)`:

'data.frame':   36199 obs. of  1 variable:
$ words: chr  "jed" "tag" "neu" "verunsichern" ...

When I use following code for the bigram analysis `bigrams <- df %>% unnest_tokens_(bigram, words, token = "ngrams", n = 2)` my output has only NA's:

`head(bigrams)`:
|          |         bigram |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1.content| NA             |
| 2.content| NA             |

I needed to clean the loaded text before with tm_map function and then I created the df as follows:
`df0 <- data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(myVCorpus,` [`, "content")), stringsAsFactors=F)` and `df<- df0 %>% unnest_tokens(words, text)`. I made an update to the latest R and updated my packages. I really do not know, why it stopped working.

Thank you in advance for your comments.
Kind regards
Christoph

Update:
It must have something to do with the prepared df. If I use the df, where the whole sentence is in one cell before I cleaned it, it works. Thats my procedure how I cleand the text:
`df<- %>% unnest_tokens(word, text)`
`myVCorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(df))`
`myVCorpus <- tm_map(text.prep, removeWords, stopwords(kind= "de"))`

Update2:
I found the solution. I needed to untidy the prepared df and this post helped: [Opposite of unnest_tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734501/opposite-of-unnest-tokens/46737676#46737676) with the following code `text.ngram<-df%>%  group_by(mygroupingvariable) %>%  summarize(text = str_c(words, collapse = " ")) %>% ungroup()`

Comment: Are you receiving any warnings in the console?

Comment: you need to use your df0 for creating the bigrams, not df. df is already unnested and can't be used for creating bigrams.

Comment: @AdamSampson: No, i do not receive any warnings. If I simply use `text<-data.frame(text="Das ist gut.")` and then do `text.bigrams <- text %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = bigram, input = text, token = "ngrams", n = 2)` it works but not with the df, which I cleaned in a VCorpus.
If I use df0, I get the error: "Must extract column with a single valid subscript. x Subscript var has size 980 but must be size 1." .